# Selecting an argument from a list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

This program is to print Student details and all. There is an `activity` in institute class. They are the available activities and students need to choose anyone from that. Then i want to print the number of students who selected each activity.

For example:

Swimming: 2 students.

Playing: 1 student.

Painting: 1 student.

Singing: 0  and so on..

Help me to print as above

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {
    int rollNo, yearOfStudy;
    String fName, lName, activity;
    Student(int rollNo, String fName, String lName, int yearOfStudy, String activity) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("RollNo.").append(rollNo).append(", ").append(fName).append(" ").append(lName)
                .toString();
    }
    void display() {
        System.out.println("Roll Number: " + rollNo + "\nName: " + fName + " " + lName + "\nYear Of Study: "
                + yearOfStudy + "\nActivity: " + activity);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Student s1 = new Student(1, "Alex", "Iwobi", 2013, "Swimming");
Student s2 = new Student(2, "Denis", "Suarez", 2013, "Painting");
Student s3 = new Student(3, "Gerard", "Deulofeu", 2013, "Swimming");
Student s4 = new Student(4, "Emre", "Can", 2013, "Playing");

Institute in = new Institute();

in.studentDetails(s1);
in.studentDetails(s2);
in.studentDetails(s3);
in.studentDetails(s4);

in.print();
in.messFood();

}

}
```

**Institute Class**

```
public class Institute {

ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();

void studentDetails(Object S) {

studentList.add(S);

}

void print() {
Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
Student s = (Student) it.next();
s.display();
}
}

void messFood() {
for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {

Student randomStudent = (Student) getRandomItem(studentList);

System.out.println("Mess food Incharge for week " + j + " : " + randomStudent.toString());

}
}

private static <T> T getRandomItem(List<T> studentList) {
return studentList.get(new Random().nextInt(studentList.size()));
}

void act() {
Set<String> activity = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
activity.add("Swimming");
activity.add("Reading");
activity.add("Playing");
activity.add("Singing");
activity.add("Painting");
}
}
```

Comment: what output you are getting right now ?

Comment: You didn't ask any question. What's your question?

Comment: dont know how to get a single argument from list. eg:`Student s1 = new Student(1, "Alex", "Iwobi", 2013, "Swimming"); ` i want to take only swimming outside to count .

Comment: [edit] your question with your comment, it is the only question you've asked. Read [ask] questions. Also learn to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:: Just call this method from main class.

Output is:

{Playing=1, Swimming=2, Painting=1}

```
public void numberOfStudentsWhoSelectedEachActivity(){
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(Object s : studentList){
            Student student = (Student) s;
            String act = student.activity;
            if(map.get(act) == null){
                map.put(act, 1);
            }
            else{
                map.put(act, map.get(act)+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

Comment: Dont have link with `act()`. also want to print singing: 0

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, int> activity = new HashMap<>();

void act() {
activity.add("Swimming",0);
activity.add("Reading",0);
activity.add("Playing",0);
activity.add("Singing",0);
activity.add("Painting",0);
}
```

when adding

```
void studentDetails(Object S) {
Student s = (Student) S;
//update activity
map.put(s.activity, map.get(s.activity) + 1);
studentList.add(S);
}
```

you can print later

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of collections,
You need to pass your studentList to it.

```
Set<String> studentSet = new HashSet<String>(students);
for (String key : studentSet) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(students, key));
}
```

Comment: The output will be Swimming: 2 
Playing: 1
Painting: 1